# Using a Magic Trackpad and a USB mouse at the same time

Tags: magic-trackpad

I know that the Magic Trackpad is not good for a few things (I personally don’t like trackpads in general too much when I’m on a laptop). I tend to start looking for a mouse. (18 years of mousing around may be too much for my old brain).

However, there are certain things about the Magic Trackpad, that could be handy and that are virtually impossible with a mouse. I don’t like the Magic Mouse because you *have* to lift your “left button click finger” to perform a right click. (I’ve tried it for a while).

So I was thinking, has anyone connected a Magic Trackpad and a USB mouse at the same time, is it possible to have both (and working) and move the hand to either when needed?

Anyone experienced this?

Comment: Just a comment, not an answer… So far as I know, you can have as many input devices connected as the USB specs allow. One good reason to do this is to avoid RSI issues. At one point, I was regularly switching between a mouse, a trackball, a trackpad, *and* a tablet to minimize the stress (and pain) on my wrist. OS X handled it all with ease.

Comment: @Dori thanks for the additional info. I believe you went **too** far in the “multiple devices” :) The magic trackpad is nice for the gestures, but I wouldn’t change my Mouse :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this works. I have a Magic Trackpad and a Logitech MX Revolution (wireless, through a USB dongle) connected to my Mac at the same time and change between them at will. Have never had any problems with this setup - I even use it both at home and at work.

Comment: +1, we have an iMac with a Magic Mouse and a Magic Trackpad. Each does some things better than the other, the hybrid works well :). This is the same as having a mouse plugged into a laptop with a trackpad. Sometimes, you just need a mouse.